# mySQL Having Exclusion optimisation

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, having

I've actually managed to get this working, but was wondering if any Guru's might be able to provide a more optimal approach:

```
SELECT `cfc`.`card_face_id`
FROM `card_face_color` AS `cfc`
INNER JOIN `color` AS `c` ON c.color_id = cfc.color_id
WHERE c.c_url IN ('black', 'blue')
AND card_face_id NOT IN (
    SELECT `cfc`.`card_face_id`
    FROM `card_face_color` AS `cfc`
    INNER JOIN `color` AS `c` ON cfc.color_id = c.color_id
    WHERE c.c_url NOT IN ('black', 'blue')
)
GROUP BY `cfc`.`card_face_id`
HAVING (COUNT(DISTINCT c.c_url) = 2)
```

Essentially I'm trying to select all card_faces that contain black and blue, but no other colors (each card_face could potentially upto 5). Tried doing it using an inner join, but this was nearly 25x slower. I'm pretty happy with my indexes, I'm just in-experienced with the Having clause.

**UPDATE**

Running `EXPLAIN` against the query reveals this (apologies about the formatting).

```
id select_type table type  possible_keys key      key_len ref                   rows Extra
1  PRIMARY     c      index PRIMARY,c_url c_url    50      NULL                  10   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  PRIMARY     cfc    ref   color_id      color_id 1       site.co.uk.c.color_id 1156 Using where; Using index
2  SUBQUERY    c      range PRIMARY,c_url c_url    50      NULL                  9    Using where; Using index
2  SUBQUERY    cfc    ref   color_id      color_id 1       site.co.uk.c.color_id 1156 Using index
```

Comment: Guru's want to know what mysql thinks about that query, please provide an execution plan (by running your query with EXPLAIN infront of it)

Comment: Thanks Puggan, updated as per your request... this query is actually part of a much larger dynamic (PHP/Zend) query, hence my desire to optimise it as much as possible.

Comment: Is the query always limited to two colors or will it have to be extensible to more than 2?

Comment: Hi Holger, It needs to be extensible, typically this could be anything from 1 to 5 values (although it could go upto 10, which would return nothing).

Comment: is `(card_face_id, color_id)` in `card_face_color` unique? and is c_url in color unique?

Comment: (card_face_id, color_id) are a compound primary key and c_url is an indexed unique value :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach.  I tried first limiting the result set to card faces that ONLY have 2 colors.  Let me know if the performance is any better.

```
SELECT cfc2.card_face_id, COUNT(*) AS cardcount2
FROM card_face_color cfc2 
  INNER JOIN color c ON cfc2.color_id=c.color_id AND c.c_url IN ('black','blue')
  INNER JOIN (SELECT cfc.card_face_id, COUNT(*) AS cardcount
              FROM card_face_color cfc
              GROUP BY cfc.card_face_id
              HAVING cardcount=2) AS color_counter ON cfc2.card_face_id=color_counter.card_face_id
GROUP BY cfc2.card_face_id
HAVING cardcount2=2
```

**APPROACH 2**

Another off the wall approach:

```
SELECT card_face_id, SUM(U.counter) AS counter FROM
(
SELECT cfc2.card_face_id, 1 AS counter
FROM card_face_color cfc2 
  INNER JOIN color c ON cfc2.color_id=c.color_id AND c.c_url IN ('black','blue')

UNION ALL

SELECT cfc2.card_face_id, 100 AS counter
FROM card_face_color cfc2 
  INNER JOIN color c ON cfc2.color_id=c.color_id AND NOT c.c_url IN ('black','blue')

) AS U
GROUP BY card_face_id
HAVING counter=2
```

**APPROACH 3**
I'm not sure how flexible you, but in this approach I eliminated the inner join:

```
SET @blue_id = (SELECT color_id FROM color WHERE c_url='blue');
SET @black_id = (SELECT color_id FROM color WHERE c_url='black');

SELECT card_face_id, SUM(U.counter) AS counter FROM
(
SELECT cfc2.card_face_id, 1 AS counter
FROM card_face_color cfc2 
WHERE cfc2.color_id IN (@blue_id,@black_id)

UNION ALL

SELECT cfc2.card_face_id, 100 AS counter
FROM card_face_color cfc2 
WHERE cfc2.color_id NOT IN (@blue_id,@black_id)

) AS U
GROUP BY card_face_id
HAVING counter=2
```

Comment: Thanks Holger, it took me a minute but I see where you going with this :) Running this dropped the query time ~23ms down to ~18ms... could it be optimised further I wonder?

Comment: @Ben,  I added a second unorthodox approach.

Comment: awesome thank you. That query takes ~40ms for the 1st hit and then ~0.8ms for each subsequent (fast). However as this is part of a big dynamic query, I'm not sure if that would help overall performance or not.

Comment: @Ben, Okay, last try.  I've eliminated the INNER JOIN by using declared variables.  Let me know.

Comment: I dont think its going to be practical to do it this way... but it took ~40ms to complete anyway. 18ms is winning (consistently)! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few version of the query

1. Is this better or worse? (~30ms)
   **filter by group_concat**

   ```
   SELECT `cfc`.`card_face_id`
   FROM `card_face_color` AS `cfc`
   INNER JOIN `color` AS `c` ON c.color_id = cfc.color_id
   GROUP BY `cfc`.`card_face_id`
   HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(c.c_url ORDER BY c.c_url) = 'black,blue'
   ```
2. this maybe use the index better (~35ms)
   **good = 2 and bad = 0**

   ```
   SELECT `cfc`.`card_face_id`
   FROM `card_face_color` AS `cfc`
   INNER JOIN `color` AS `c` ON c.color_id = cfc.color_id
   GROUP BY `cfc`.`card_face_id`
   HAVING
     SUM(IF(c.c_url IN ('black','blue'), 1, NULL)) = 2 AND
     SUM(IF(c.c_url IN ('black','blue'), NULL, 1)) = 0
   ```
3. As the 2nd faild, i try one more time with DISTINCT this time (~34ms)
   **Total = 2 and good = 2**

   ```
   SELECT `cfc`.`card_face_id`
   FROM `card_face_color` AS `cfc`
   INNER JOIN `color` AS `c` ON c.color_id = cfc.color_id
   GROUP BY `cfc`.`card_face_id`
   HAVING
     COUNT(DISTINCT c.c_url) = 2 AND
     COUNT(DISTINCT IF(c.c_url IN ('black','blue'), c.c_url, NULL)) = 2
   ```
4. Lets twist it a bit more,
   **total = 2 and bad = 0**

   ```
   SELECT `cfc`.`card_face_id`
   FROM `card_face_color` AS `cfc`
   INNER JOIN `color` AS `c` ON c.color_id = cfc.color_id
   GROUP BY `cfc`.`card_face_id`
   HAVING
     COUNT(DISTINCT c.c_url) = 2 AND
     COUNT(IF(c.c_url IN ('black','blue'), NULL, c.c_url)) = 0
   ```
5. just to test all cobination,
   **good = 2 and bad = 0**

   ```
   SELECT `cfc`.`card_face_id`
   FROM `card_face_color` AS `cfc`
   INNER JOIN `color` AS `c` ON c.color_id = cfc.color_id
   GROUP BY `cfc`.`card_face_id`
   HAVING
     COUNT(DISTINCT IF(c.c_url IN ('black','blue'), c.c_url, NULL)) = 2 AND
     COUNT(IF(c.c_url IN ('black','blue'), NULL, c.c_url)) = 0
   ```

Comment: Thank puggan. This is worse, takes ~30ms to run, a fun technique though!

Comment: Yes of course :) ... the 2nd doesn't return any rows, but takes ~35ms to run. Thanks btw for sorting out the editing.

Comment: i used the first one a few times, becouse its fast to write, about half the lenth of your sql, but never tested it's speed

Comment: can you try the 3th too :-), its intresting to see whats most effectiv :-)

Comment: #3 takes ~34ms but does return the expected data :) I am intrigued as well, just lack the experience to be quite this creative. Thanks again!

Comment: #4 returns all the expected results, but takes anything from ~31ms to ~35ms, seems to be having a hard time giving consistant timings :)

Comment: #5 like #4 timings are a little more random but takes between ~33ms and ~37ms. Very thorough :)

Comment: time for me to go to bed, intresting that #1 was fastest of mine, hope you at least got some creativite ideas from me (and Holger)

Comment: You were both very helpful and its greatly appreciated. Thank you both :)